# Android - Widget to Play Video (onclick trouble)

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to make a simple widget that will play a movie from the sdcard when clicked on.  This seems simple enough, and by following tutorials I've come up with the following code, but it seems the onclick is never setup.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="WidgetProvider" android:label="DVD Cover">          
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info_2x4"/>
        </receiver>
```

Layout (widget.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/holder"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff777777"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/cover"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#000000"

/>
</LinearLayout>
```

appwidget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:minWidth="200dip"
   android:minHeight="300dip"
   android:updatePeriodMillis="180000"
   android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
   >
</appwidget-provider>
```

WidgetProvider.java:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


            String movieurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Movie.mp4";


           Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,0);


            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.holder, contentIntent);


            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: That's the tutorial I used to begin, but the clicks are not being received.  Do you see a discrepancy between my code and the tutorial I should target?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

First create a variable something like this

```
public static String CLICK_ACTION = "com.widget.CLICK";
```

Now inside `onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)` method set pending intent like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < appWidgetIds.length; j++) {
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  R.layout.widget);
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);

    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION);
                clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.cover, pendingIntent_);
}
```

Then in `onReceive(final Context context, Intent main_intent)` method do like this.

```
 if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION)) {
         //Start your video intent here
         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(notificationIntent);

            }
```

Comment: Tried this but still no luck.  I tried logging the onReceive event and it's not registering it at all.

Comment: First of all you need to create a widget that handles some click event. then after that you can proceed with your video work. Try to first implement the tutorials for this.

Comment: I feel I have done everything in the tutorials as well as your suggestion to handle the click event.  Do you see something missing from my code above?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code but the code provided by me is a working code.

Comment: More help and working examples hare :-https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid